# How do I combine an IF statement with an IF(OR) statement?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
Statement 1 =IF(A1<=B1,"NO TAX",A1-B1)  
Statement 2 =IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1)),"",A1-B1)
```

They both work separately but I don't know how to get them to work together in the same cell.

[image: example of both formulas working in 2 different scenarios]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to first check if either A1 or B1 are empty, in which case you want to do nothing (leave an empty cell), and if both have values check if B1 can be subtracted from A1 and write the result, otherwise write "NO TAX".

The combined formula is:

`=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1)), "", IF(A1<=B1,"NO TAX",A1-B1))`

Comment: Glad to help. Consider marking this as the answer. Thanks.